# Coreutils (or otherwise) `ls`: don't append symbol indicating type when piped

Tags: command-line, ls, coreutils

Is there a way to get GNU coreutils `ls` (or any other open-source `ls`) to omit the trailing symbol (`*` for executable, `/` for directory, etc.) only when output is piped?

the GNU `ls` has a `--color[=WHEN]` option accepting `auto` to automatically show colors when output is not piped, and omit the control sequences for colors when output is piped. I am looking for identical behavior regarding trailing symbols indicating filetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have an alias for `ls` that's unconditionally adding the `-F` (or `--classify`) option. I would work around that by creating a wrapper function that tests whether the stdout is a terminal or not; only add the `-F` option if the output is a terminal.

```
function ls {
  if [ -t 1 ]
  then
    command ls -F "$@"
  else
    command ls "$@"
  fi
}
```

Adjust the other default options as you like.